# Unable to select date in calendar - selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class IbiboCalendar {
WebDriver driver;

String selectDepartureDate = "07/25/2017";
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Date selectedDepartureDate = new Date(selectDepartureDate);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDepartureDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM/dd/yyyy");
String formattedDeaparturedate = simpleDepartureDate.format(selectedDepartureDate);

String[] split = formattedDeaparturedate.split("/");
String departureMonth = split[0]+" "+split[2];
String departureDate = split[1];


@FindBy(css = "input[placeholder = 'Choose Date']")
WebElement iDepartDateCalendarBox;



public IbiboCalendar(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

public void goToDepartDateCalendarBox() throws InterruptedException{
    iDepartDateCalendarBox.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    while(true){ 
        try{ 
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'DayPicker-Month.DayPicker-Caption'] and [contains(text(),'"+departureMonth+"')]")).isDisplayed();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'DayPicker-Day.calDate'] and [contains(text(),'"+departureDate+"')]")).click();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class= 'DayPicker-NavButton DayPicker-NavButton--next']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        }



}
```

}

I am calling the above class by creating an object of it ,to select a date.The problem I face is ,system keeps on clicking the "Next" arrow button in the month.Also I get error in the xpath selector syntax.Kindly help me out.

```
public class IbiboTest {

 static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}


@Test
public void testIbiboHomePage() throws InterruptedException{
    IbiboHomePage home = PageFactory.initElements(driver, com.Nalini.Ibibo.IbiboHomePage.class);
    home.clickRoundTripRadioButton();
    home.goToFromSelectionBox();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    home.goToToSelectionBox();
    Thread.sleep(5000);


    IbiboCalendar calendar = PageFactory.initElements(driver, com.Nalini.Ibibo.IbiboCalendar.class);
    calendar.goToDepartDateCalendarBox();
    Thread.sleep(5000);



}
```

Comment: Need HTML code for datepicker

Comment: I am unable to get the html code for the entire calendar.How can i get it.

Comment: right click the element > then inspect element

Comment: @Nal You should first start working with the solutions​ provided to you & close the discussion threads before asking too many questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug and firepath addon in mozilla browser and inspect xpath using [this](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

@Nal First of all I would like to know  which date picker are you using it's a Bootstrap or `jquery` Date  picker.
For `Jquery Picker` contains Frames so you have to switch into it.
Below is the code for Jquery Date picker:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize(); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/"); 

 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-
 frame'][@src='/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html']")));

driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();

System.out.println("Datepicker Clicked");
```